# Is it possible to serve top navi only in mobile?

Tags: php, javascript, mobile

using mobile detection (js or php), is it possible to display top navi made for mobile only?
also i see a lot of mobile detection in php - where is it supposed to be placed?

```
{php}
function isMobileBrowser($user_agent = '') {
  foreach (array('iPhone','Android','Windows CE', 'PPC', 'Smartphone', 'IEMobile', 'Opera Mini') as $mobile_browser_ua_snippet) {
    if (stristr($user_agent, $mobile_browser_ua_snippet)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
{/php}

{if isMobileBrowser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])} 
{include file="templates/layouts/zones/mobileMenu.html"}
{/if}
```

now i got error: syntax error: unbalanced parenthesis in if statement => I am not sure abt that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are:

1) Execute the PHP Mobile Detection within each PHP script/page served (and/or store the result in a Session Variable, so the Detection need only run once per visit). Use the results to switch on/off parts of the markup you render (ie if the visitor is using a mobile device, then set `$isMobile` to `true`, and when you are creating the HTML, wrap the "top navi" section in a PHP conditional of `if( $isMobile==true ){` ... "top navi" ... `}`.

2) If your host allows it, create a subdomain like **m.server.com** (where "server.com" is your domain). You can then either use a **.htaccess** rule to force any mobile devices to the "m.*" subdomain, or, again, use PHP to do the same. Within that subdomain, have all of the same pages/content but optimised for a mobile device browser.

3) Use a CSS Media Queries to make the "top navi" element visible. [Using Mobile Specific HTML, CSS & Javascript](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/using-mobile-specific-html-css-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, yes.

I'd prefer to create a function:

```
function isMobileBrowser($user_agent = '') {
  foreach (array('Windows CE', 'PPC', 'Smartphone', 'IEMobile', 'Opera Mini') as $mobile_browser_ua_snippet) {
    if (stristr($user_agent, $mobile_browser_ua_snippet)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

You suggest to extract array of substrings of mobile browsers user agents from the **foreach**
Then, in your code, depending on what do you use to output HTML, you do a simple condition like:

```
if (isMobileBrowser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
include 'mobile_navi.inc.php';
}
```

I'd also suggest to create mobile version of your whole website. Let's say your sites domain name is mysite.com, you create mobile version at m.website.com and then you just redirect your mobile visitors to m.website.com just like this:

```
// THIS CODE SHOULD REMAIN **BEFORE** ANY OUTPUT!!!
if (isMobileBrowser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
  header('Location: http://m.website.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Or you can do it in apache's mod_rewrite (You will have as many RewriteConds as mobile brosers user agents substrings). I believe it's able to be done in nginx configuration file as well.

Comment: @Nemoden, thank you so much! Your function works for iphone? just wonder.

Comment: No. iPhone user agent string looks like "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; XXXXX like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A477d Safari/419.3", so just add "iPhone" to the collation array.

Comment: And you might want to add "Android" as well.

Comment: @Nemoden, sorry to ask stupid question but the function is placed in <script> part in <head>? then conditionals are placed where it should be in body?

Comment: @Nemoden, oh lol I have difficulties telling which PHP or JS it is. I have placed the codes and change the filenames for testing on the smarty template (content body) in pinnaclecart, but include isn't working as it is using smarty sort. :(

Comment: I know don't what Smarty sort is (I though Smarty does not sort anything itself), because I did not use it. You shouldn't use `include` in this case, I think you just use another template. Like, if you have templates 'nav.template.php' and 'mobile_nav.template.php'. And then you tell Smarty `if (isMobileBrowser()) { /* use mobile_nav.template.php */ } else { /* use nav.template.php*/ }`

Comment: @Nemoden, no i mean that the templates are using smarty (sorry for wrong typos). but i need to know what reserved word to tell smarty to load the html. wait, the function would have to go in the body where there is nav menu correct? then use conditional for menu files. hmm.

Comment: It is actually Smarty uses templates since Smarty is templating system :) I read a little about how Smarty works. Your code should be like this: `$smarty = new Smarty(); $smarty->display( isMobileBrowser() ? "mobile_nav.template.php" : "nav.template.php");` Your isMobileBrowser function should be somewhere in libraries you include BEFORE smarty class. Well, if you have a misunderstanding in how it works, just place the function in your index.php in the very beginning (nothing would break) and then you'll find appropriate place. Everything comes with experience ;)

Comment: @Nemoden, wow thank you :) I am trying that and hope it works. yes i have no experience in programming but i wonder if you may have any recommendation for me to start from basics - i can read and understand a bit but writing is worse in programming logics :p

Comment: I remember myself placing function named `from_windows1251_to_utf8` in the beginning of index.php :) Heck, I did not even know that where is `iconv` function there... After a while you will create files like functions.php... then you will put this files from document root to dir. like 'libraries'... or 'classes' or whatever... And then you will include this files like `include 'libraries/common_functions.inc.php'` and then you will learn about OOP and `__autoload` and will forget about requires and includes... :)

Comment: @Nemoden, one problem, my menu files are html. i place that smarty snippet in html but apparently it isnt working... hmm

Comment: @Josephine You probably need some good book covering PHP (and simple HTML) first. Unfortunately, books I read would not be good for novice and I can't suggest any books for beginners since I did not read one. First book I read about web programming was "Learning programming Perl in 24 hours", publisher was sAms (hope I did not miss-spell it). I would definitely recommend it. I tried to read one PHP book in Russian (which is my native language), but it was awful, so I self-learned PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php would help you a lot. My major suggestion is: learn from professionals.

Comment: @Josephine extension is does not matter. Smarty should compile your template anyway if it is valid Smarty template, of course. If you wrote your template according to Smarty requirements it will work properly. Does your Smarty template fetch and display your non-mobile template ?

Comment: @Nemoden, I tried placing both in the index.php and see what happened. but nothing changes.. except that the codes appear as text. i wonder how to use php in the html file and bring in other html files. The non mobile template is html file and yes I am assuming that smarty fetch and display it.

Comment: @Josephine Smarty does not support PHP code in templates. How your code looks like now ?

Comment: @Nemoden, I tried my luck placing them in menu.html file and one go in php while i use smarty if statement. still got error :(

Comment: @Nemoden, the code in html file is all ul and li. then php and if statement are placed in the html file as you see above (which i edited.)

Comment: Well, just as I thought. You should not store function in the template. You should define this function in the beginning of index.php. Then create TWO templates: one - for mobile version, other - for regular version for desktop computers. Then you just load appropriate template.

Comment: @Nemoden, i did have two html files: mobile and regular. i defined function in index.php and it didn't display the template. then I am wondering how to call the function to load appropriate html files?

Comment: a function do not load appropriate template itself, but just answers does users browser is a mobile browser. So, function return boolean (true or false). You should use returning value in condition to decide what template to load.